# Web page building with python 3.3?

Tags: python, web, wsgi

I am going through a tutorial on building a website with django. It suggests using mod_python but I have heard to stay away from that and use wsgi instead. Problem is I am running python 3.3 (and apache 2.4.2 for that matter, everything seems to be compatible with apache 2.2). Is there any way to get all of this working on 3.3? Or is my best bet to go back to python 2.7? Thanks.

Edit: I am on Windows, so that seems to be another roadblock.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using 3.3?

Comment: You can find mod_wsgi binaries for Apache 2.4, Python 3.3 and Windows at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Damn! I knew I had seen that website before but I couldn't find it. Bookmarked. Thank you!

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton So, all the files for mod_wsgi are .so. I thought all the Windows binaries would be .exe?

Comment: The .so file is loaded into the Apache process, it is not run as a separate program.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) + [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) to depoly your django site instead of Apache+mod_wsgi. Here's a [tutorial](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

As many tutorials is about how to configure the environment in Unix-like environment, you could use [cgywin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to simulate a Unix-like environment on Windows.

The version of Python you use is not much critical when you develop a site using Django except that you have to use some libraries that don't support Python-3.x.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard, between python2 and python3 there is a lot of incompatibility, and somehow the developers of the most python frameworks somehow won't understand, why they should port their software to the newer version of the language.

The simplest way if you use python 2.

The best way were to start an independent, python 3 fork of your most loved python framework.

**EDIT**: newer django supports python3, thus it should work.

Comment: Django 1.5 and 1.6 support Python 3 just fine. Yes, there's an issue with 3rd-party libs, but the framework is just fine...